# Why does Google Drive / Files / List find files from one Shared Drive but not another?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

We are working on a tool which downloads all spreadsheets in Google Drive and sends them to MySQL. This works great for My Drive. Now we have "upgraded" to G Suite for Business and have found this problem with accessing a Shared Drive.

This is using a service account. Files in one Shared Drive are listed but files in another Shared Drive are not listed. The files in the other drive will list if we specify `corpora` and `driveId`.

I have checked the following permissions:

- Permissions for the service account for the Shared Drives are the same
- No special permissions are set on intermediary folders or files

I am using Google Drives API to list files like this:

```php
$this->googleClient->setScopes(\Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
$googleService = new \Google_Service_Drive($this->googleClient);
$this->throttleIfNecessary();

// Collect file list
$optParams = [
    //'corpora'=> 'domain',
    'orderBy' => 'modifiedTime',
    'pageSize' => $count, // Google default is 100, maximum is 1000
    'q' => "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and modifiedTime >= '$modifiedTime'",
    #'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id,modifiedTime)',
    'fields' => 'files(id,modifiedTime)',
    'supportsAllDrives' => 'true',
    'includeItemsFromAllDrives' => 'true',
    'includeTeamDriveItems' => 'true',
    'supportsTeamDrives' => 'true',
    //'corpora' => 'drive',
    //'driveId' => 'oesntuheunt' // PMT Owners Shared Drive
];
print_r($optParams);
// https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list
$results = $googleService->files->listFiles($optParams);
print_r($results);
```

How will I update this so the service account can access all files across all Shared Drives?`

Comment: Does setting `corpora` to `allDrives` fix the issue?

Comment: That's the answer, thank you